# How can I get the form builder service using dependency injection?

Tags: 8, dependency-injection

How can I change form builder call in class in to dependency injection method?

My current code:

```
class CustomBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomForm');
    return $form;
  }

}
```

And I tried:

```
class CustomBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * formBuilder.   *
   */
  protected $formBuilder;

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  public function __construct($formBuilder) {
    $this->formBuilder = $formBuilder;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
        $container->get('form_builder')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $form = $this->formBuilder->getForm('Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomForm');
    return $form;
  }

}
```

But getting following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getForm() on a non-object in H:\wamp\www\myproject\modules\custom\custom_module\src\Plugin\Block\CustomBlock.php on line 44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement the `\Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface`. The `\Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase` doesn't implement it by default.

Also, your IDE is probably not that good since it would show you the `create()` method is not implemented.

Comment: The constructor is also missing the type hint.

Answer (score 3):

AJAX form test mock module's [`AjaxFormBlock.php`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.7.7/core/modules/system/tests/modules/ajax_forms_test/src/Plugin/Block/AjaxFormBlock.php) is quite a nice example for getting both in one, the form builder and the form interface! Look how it `implements FormInterface, ContainerFactoryPluginInterface` to then provide the form from within the block and injecting the form builder via dependency injection to then be used to get the form in the block's `build()` method at the same time.

Of course, when you only need the form builder, you don't need to implement the `FormInterface`! Then you just need the `ContainerFactoryPluginInterface`.

> ```
> namespace Drupal\ajax_forms_test\Plugin\Block;
>
> use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
> use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
> use Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface;
> use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
> use Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface;
> use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
> use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
>
> /**
>  * Provides an AJAX form block.
>  *
>  * @Block(
>  *   id = "ajax_forms_test_block",
>  *   admin_label = @Translation("AJAX test form"),
>  *   category = @Translation("Forms")
>  * )
>  */
> class AjaxFormBlock extends BlockBase implements FormInterface, ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {
>
>   /**
>    * The form builder.
>    *
>    * @var \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface
>    */
>   protected $formBuilder;
>
>   /**
>    * The messenger.
>    *
>    * @var \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface
>    */
>   protected $messenger;
>
>   /**
>    * Constructs a new AjaxFormBlock.
>    *
>    * @param array $configuration
>    *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
>    * @param string $plugin_id
>    *   The plugin ID for the plugin instance.
>    * @param mixed $plugin_definition
>    *   The plugin implementation definition.
>    * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface $form_builder
>    *   The form builder.
>    * @param \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface $messenger
>    *   The messenger.
>    */
>   public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FormBuilderInterface $form_builder, MessengerInterface $messenger) {
>     parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
>     $this->formBuilder = $form_builder;
>     $this->messenger = $messenger;
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    */
>   public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
>     return new static(
>       $configuration,
>       $plugin_id,
>       $plugin_definition,
>       $container->get('form_builder'),
>       $container->get('messenger')
>     );
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    */
>   public function build() {
>     return $this->formBuilder->getForm($this);
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    */
>   public function getFormId() {
>     return 'ajax_forms_test_block';
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    */
>   public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
>     $form['test1'] = [
>       '#type' => 'select',
>       '#title' => $this->t('Test 1'),
>       '#required' => TRUE,
>       '#options' => [
>         'option1' => $this->t('Option 1'),
>         'option2' => $this->t('Option 2'),
>       ],
>       '#ajax' => [
>         'callback' => '::updateOptions',
>         'wrapper' => 'edit-test1-wrapper',
>       ],
>       '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-test1-wrapper">',
>       '#suffix' => '</div>',
>     ];
>     $form['actions'] = [
>       '#type' => 'actions',
>     ];
>     $form['actions']['submit'] = [
>       '#type' => 'submit',
>       '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
>     ];
>     return $form;
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * Updates the options of a select list.
>    *
>    * @param array $form
>    *   An associative array containing the structure of the form.
>    * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
>    *   The current state of the form.
>    *
>    * @return array
>    *   The updated form element.
>    */
>   public function updateOptions(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
>     $form['test1']['#options']['option1'] = $this->t('Option 1!!!');
>     $form['test1']['#options'] += [
>       'option3' => $this->t('Option 3'),
>       'option4' => $this->t('Option 4'),
>     ];
>     return $form['test1'];
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    */
>   public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    */
>   public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
>     $this->messenger->addStatus('Submission successful.');
>   }
>
> }
> ```

---

Another nice example is core's [`SearchBlock.php`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.9.10/core/modules/search/src/Plugin/Block/SearchBlock.php).

Also worth checking out the docs on [Dependency injection in Plugin (Block)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/dependency-injection-in-plugin-block).

Answer (score 1):

Try this this solution will work.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\firstcustommodule\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a 'Hello' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "hello_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Hello Block")
 * )
 */
class HelloBlock extends BlockBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {

  /**
   * The form builder service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface
   */
  protected $formBuilder;

  /**
   * Constructs a HelloBlock object.
   *
   * @param array $configuration
   *   A configuration array containing information about the plugin instance.
   * @param string $plugin_id
   *   The plugin ID for the plugin instance.
   * @param mixed $plugin_definition
   *   The plugin implementation definition.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface $form_builder
   *   The form builder.
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FormBuilderInterface $form_builder) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $this->formBuilder = $form_builder;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    // Instantiate this block class.
    return new static($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition,
      // Load the service required to construct this class.
      $container->get('form_builder')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return $this->formBuilder->getForm('Drupal\firstcustommodule\Form\CompanyAddForm');
  }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple Answer with updated code you just forgot to Import namespace at top and you have not defined the **FormBuilderInterface** type of object @ constructor

```
 use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 class CustomBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * The form builder.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface
   */
   protected $formBuilder;

  /**
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilderInterface $form_builder The Form Builder.
   */

  public function __construct(FormBuilderInterface $formBuilder) {
    $this->formBuilder = $formBuilder;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
        $container->get('form_builder')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $form = $this->formBuilder->getForm('Drupal\custom_module\Form\CustomForm');
    return $form;
  }

}
```

Comment: To `use` a namespace unfortunately is no dependency injection.

Comment: The `use`statement declares which interfaces/classes/traits are used, but that doesn't inject dependencies.